# PHP: send POST request then read XML response?

Tags: php, xml, post, simplexml

I'm trying to write a PHP script that sends a POST request to a remote server, then parses the XML response.

I can do the POST request, but am having difficulty (from other SO questions) working out how to parse the XML response.

My current code gives me: `Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: I/O warning : failed to load external entity "1" in /Users/simon/usercreate.php on line 46` - the `simplexml_load_file($response)` line.

I'm working on a local server, not sure if that makes a difference. Code:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);
$response = curl_exec ($curl);
curl_close ($curl);
echo $response;
$rxml = simplexml_load_file($response);
echo $rxml->title;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use [simplexml_load_string](http://php.net/simplexml_load_string) instead of `simplexml_load_file`

Answer (score 3):

You have to set the cURL option to return the transfer

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of loading a file, you want to load a string.

```
// Instead of
$rxml = simplexml_load_file($response);

// You want
$rxml = simplexml_load_string($response);
```